# MySQL timestamp field does not accept unix_timestamp() result

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with a column named *date* of *TIMESTAMP* type.
I'm trying to load big amount of data using *LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE*.
Everything works, except that the date column cant be filled with a custom unix timestamp created from a string. Here is the SQL query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.csv' INTO TABLE names FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@nm) set `name`=@nm, `gender`='female', `date`=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2015-06-07 09:21:44', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'));
```

Also tryed this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.csv' INTO TABLE names FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@nm) set `name`=@nm, `gender`='female', `date`=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-06-07 09:21:44');
```

The problem is, that the date field is filled with *0000-00-00 00:00:00* .

Have anybody any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` data type, do you mean `TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: Yes, you're right! Sorry!

Comment: Corrected, thanks for mentioning!

Comment: Try removing the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and `STR_TO_DATE` function. `TIMESTAMP` fields work with the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format (same as `DATETIME`).

Comment: @Vatev, could you move your comment to an answer? You provided it first and it works.

Comment: Not all timestamps are Unix timestamps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and `STR_TO_DATE` function.

`TIMESTAMP` fields work with the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format (same as `DATETIME`).

Answer (score 1):

If `date` is datatype `TIMESTAMP`, just do

```
 `date` = '2015-06-07 09:21:44'
```

No need for the rigmarole with the `STR_TO_DATE` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. MySQL does an implicit conversion of a string literal (in that format) to `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP` datatype when in a context that expects one of those datatypes.

You'd want to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function to return an integer value, if you were storing the value into a numeric column, rather than a `TIMESTAMP`.

---

Comment: Your answer is right, thanks for the help. However, @Vatev 's comment came first, I need to give him the acceptance. Thanks anyway for the help!